# Create a n x n board in Racket using build-list

Tags: list, function, racket

So I'm trying to a build a function in which it creates a list of positions on a board based on an inputed dimension.

(define (create-board dimension) ...)

Where dimension would be a number from 1 to 9, inclusive.

So the output would a list of lists of board locations where the board locations would be a 2 digit number, the first digit being the row number, second being the column number.

Example:

(create board 3) -> (list (list 11 12 13) (list 21 22 23) (list 31 32 33)))

Additionally, this is supposed to be done without recursion or helper functions, only abstract list functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Racket, there's a very idiomatic solution using [iterations and comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html):

```
(define (create-board dim)
  (for/list ([i (in-range 1 (add1 dim))])
    (for/list ([j (in-range 1 (add1 dim))])
      (+ (* 10 i) j))))
```

Alternatively, using only elementary list procedures:

```
(define (create-board dim)
  (map (lambda (i)
         (map (lambda (j) 
                (+ (* 10 i) j))
              (build-list dim add1)))
       (build-list dim add1)))
```

For example:

```
(create-board 3)
=> '((11 12 13) (21 22 23) (31 32 33))
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I can only do this in Intermediate Student with Lambda. So for/list wouldn't be defined. I know there's many ways to easily do this in the full language, but unfortunately i'm restricted which is why i'm having trouble